# Select PDF from sdcard in Android

Tags: android

I want to select PDF file from sdcard and upload to server in my android project. Please help me to do that. If possible please show me the code to do that. I also tried with video select sample code, but it shows "**No application can perform this Action**".
`enter code here`

```
Button b1;
private static final int SELECT_VIDEO_DIALOG = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("pdf/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), SELECT_VIDEO_DIALOG);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_VIDEO_DIALOG)
        {
            System.out.println("SELECT_VIDEO");
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String selectedpath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("SELECT_VIDEO Path : " + selectedpath);
        }
    }
}

private String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE, MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION}; 
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst(); 
    String filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA));
    int fileSize = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE));
    long duration = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION)));
    //some extra potentially useful data to help with filtering if necessary
    System.out.println("size: " + fileSize);
    System.out.println("path: " + filePath);
    System.out.println("duration: " + duration);

    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: At which moment do you see `No application can perform this Action`? Your code in the onClick handler works for me.

Comment: I get that message while I am clicking the button for select pdf from sdcard.

Comment: So then now you know the reason. You have no suitable apps to pick a file installed on your device. Start with installing file explorers/managers.

Comment: What I want to do for that? We can get the video file from sdcard without using any 3rd party app.Then why we want to use another app to pick pdf file from sdcard?

Comment: You wanted it yourself. The code in onClick uses another app to pick a file.

Comment: Do you have any sample code for that? If you have can you please post it here?

Comment: Please ask somebody around to discuss together this post. He/She can advise you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi  if you want file to     be listed than you can use

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("file/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_RESULT_CODE);
```

if you want only PDF file than follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/27407812/4741746