# Android Custom FileChooser

Tags: android, file, android-intent, file-extension, filechooser

In my app the user has the opportunity to import a file via an intent.

```
 Intent chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(new Helper(FunctionsActivity.this).getPathToAppFolder());
            chooseFile.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
            chooseFile.setType("*/*");
            Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, getString(R.string.importDatei));
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_IMPORT_FILE);
```

The valid files are files with the ending: **.tr**
These can undestood by my app.
The problem is, that the Intent shows all files in the folder:

[image: See here]

After long searching I could not find a solution to show only **.tr** files. (Besides: For .xml or known file formats it is possible.)
So my idea is to write a small custom filechooser. When you click on "import", an activity opens that shows the names of all files with the extension .tr

So my question is:
Has anyone implemented something like this and can help me or does anyone has tips how to implement this the best?
I am grateful for everything that helps me further

Comment: http://android-arsenal.com/tag/35

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried a lot of them and they all suck. So I want to write my own.

Comment: @CommonsWare l0v3 y0u Mark :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android file chooser with specific file extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407157/android-file-chooser-with-specific-file-extensions)