# Intent to pick file from the specified directory in internal storage

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to create `Intent` which will show me a file picker to choose files inside the specified folder. I used this approach:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri selectedUri = Uri.parse(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/FILES");
intent.setDataAndType(selectedUri, "*/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, SCRIPT_REQUEST_CODE);
```

But this didn't open the desired folder.

Can somebody tell how to open the file picker in the specified folder?

UPD: Tried this as were suggested in comments but I can't pick the desired file type with such type in intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_RESULT_CODE);
```

Comment: there are lots of related questions and answers, have you tried them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use intent for choosing file browser to select file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923760/how-to-use-intent-for-choosing-file-browser-to-select-file)

Comment: @user1506104 Tried this as were suggested but I can't pick the desired file type with such type in intent.

Comment: did you try with intent.setType("\*/\*")?

Comment: @user1506104 yes, it just shows me all types of files.  no filtering

Comment: what type of file/s that you want to filter?

Comment: @user1506104 `.scr`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407157/android-file-chooser-with-specific-file-extensions