# Open file dialog with extension filter for a custom extension with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, filter, openfiledialog

Is there any way to set a file extension filter for this intent:
I want to filter files with this extension ".xxx"

```
val intent = Intent()
                .setType("*/*") // <- it doesn't work if I put it here (".xxx")
                .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a file (.xxx)"), OPEN_FILE_CODE)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android file chooser with specific file extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407157/android-file-chooser-with-specific-file-extensions)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was looking for something better than interact a list of all files and then select those which have the extension that I wish... isn't there any way to add a filter like ``.setExtensionFilter(".xxx") `` ? thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to set a file extension filter for this intent

No, sorry.

> `it doesn't work if I put it here (".xxx")`

That is because `setType()` takes a MIME type, not a file extension. If your file extension is common and maps to a well-known MIME type, you might try using that MIME type with `setType()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! the extension I need is ```.shp```. So, it is not so well-known. I think I will do this filter "by hand".